# My ATI Radeon Video Card still has quite bad performance in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, ati

This question might be answered, but I would like to get an answer. I should have 11.04 Beta 2, but because I have updated the packages, then I guess I have 11.04 "Retail". And I have an ATI Radeon HD 4800 video card. When I was using Ubuntu 10.10, then effects, for example the Wobbly Windows, were very fast and looked great. But now, they are quite laggy.

Is there anything to do to help that?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. I tried updating drivers, changing Compiz settings and even disabling Unity, still no luck. Used to work like a charm on 10.10 and 10.04.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the latest ati catalyst - [ati-catalyst-114](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/amd-ati-catalyst-114-released-just-in.html) or try the steps given in this blog - [installing hardware drivers in ubuntu](http://www.linoob.com/2011/04/installing-hardware-drivers-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: @Mihkel Glad I could be of help! now tick mark the answer to close the question.